# How to access array of fields from a form in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

Please forgive me if this question is a duplicate, because I could not find the answer to this question anywhere else on Stack Overflow.

I have a form in ASP.NET that has multiple fields, and more fields can be added through jQuery. In my form, I want an array of friends.

This is the friend class:

```
public class Friend {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

This is my form, and users can add as many friends as they want, by clicking a button that adds a row with these two fields. For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <input type="text" name="friend[0].Name" />
        <input type="text" name="friend[0].Age" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="text" name="friend[1].Name" />
        <input type="text" name="friend[1].Age" />
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="text" name="friend[2].Name" />
        <input type="text" name="friend[2].Age" />
    </tr>
    ...
</table>
```

How would I access these as a list of friends, in my function in the controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I Think you're almost there,

```
<form method="post" action="/Home/UpdateFriends">

    <input type="text" name="[0].Name" value="Curious George" />
    <input type="text" name="[0].Age" value="20" />

    <input type="text" name="[1].Name" value="Code Complete" />
    <input type="text" name="[1].Age" value="50" />



    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

controller should look like this

```
//Action method on HomeController
public ActionResult UpdateFriends(ICollection<Friend> friends) {
    //your code here
}
```

[this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) explains it more in depth.